# What does Vivek Ramaswamy mean by "fourth branch of government"?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

In Vivek Ramaswamy's "[ten commandments](https://www.foxnews.com/politics/vivek-ramaswamy-shares-10-commandments-2024-campaign-starts-god-real-two-genders)", he says:

> There are three branches of the U.S. government, not four

What is the implied fourth branch in this context?

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72098/is-there-any-academic-research-into-the-concept-of-government-does-not-control

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, I find it useful to mentally discard all political statements that do not contain an "and here is how we are going to do it instead" rider.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that they are called "ten commandments". Also, from the article, ""There are only two genders" — the latter being a contentious claim by those on the Left." What?

Comment: Traditionally that term, or more commonly "fourth estate", is used to refer to the Press. That may not be what he meant though.

Comment: NYTimes [Fact-Checking Vivek Ramaswamy on the Campaign Trail](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/08/26/us/politics/vivek-ramaswamy-2024-campaign-fact-check.html)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on these two posts, Ramaswamy's implied fourth branch is the administrative state.

On [X, formerly Twitter](https://twitter.com/VivekGRamaswamy/status/1664729510317637632?lang=en).

> I will shut down the fourth branch of government, the administrative state. You cannot tame that beast. You must end it.

On [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/VivekGRamaswamy/posts/pfbid02iGKx5B5UVUFjyr8mujRPgo1oHMk7dHCyJKWq3afxCfWZAdPzb4vngSrnRugAXkeYl).

> TRUTH: You cannot tame the fourth branch of government. You must end it. I will shut down the administrative state.

Comment: (+1) Althoug that sounds as plausible as banning gravity over US land... and probably with similar side-effects.

Comment: So he’s referring to the bureaucracy, the departments and agencies, per [Dwight Waldo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Administrative_State)? But… that’s the executive branch…

Comment: @TimPederick - Congress delegates authority to the various executive departments. That delegation is in the form of goals with some restrictions. It is up to those departments to create regulations consistent with those laws, Conservatives frequently complain that those regulations, by liberals or progressives, go beyond the delegated authority or intent of Congress, In that sense (over-regulation), these unelected bureaucrats are running the country, effectively as a fourth branch of government.

Comment: @TimPederick While they're technically part of the executive branch, they often operate somewhat autonomously, because it's difficult for POTUS's office to micro-manage them.

Comment: @RickSmith The conservative courts that Trump put in place have been rolling back some of that authority. There was a landmark case a couple of years ago that took away much of the EPA's ability to regulate based on the Clean Water Act.

Comment: @Barmar it's also in most cases explicitly not within the president's power to "shut down" these agencies because they are established by statute. He'd need to get Congress to pass a bill to eliminate them.

Comment: @phoog He can't shut them down, but he has administrative control over them. He selects their administrators (with Senate approval), and can use executive orders to tell them how to do their jobs.

Comment: @Barmar that is true to some extent; the executive orders have to be consistent with the statutory mandates.  If there's a law saying that the director of the FBI or the attorney general "shall" do something then an executive order cannot simply erase that duty.  But at issue here is a promise to "shut down" several agencies, not to exercise administrative control over them.

Comment: When a Presidential candidate (or actual POTUS) says they're going to do something, it often means they plan on working with Congress to implement that plan, unless it's something that can actually be implemented by EO.

Comment: @phoog Like when Trump promised to repeal and replace Obamacare.

Comment: @Barmar sure, but with things such as tax rates and federal programs such as Obamacare that is more obvious to most people.  A lot of people do not realize that the structure of the executive branch is not at the president's discretion but rather at congress's direction.

Comment: A president can have a lot of control over the administrative state by issuing an EO that laws have to be interpreted by executive agencies as narrowly as possible and they cannot unilaterally create laws with broad interpretations. E.g. the current controversy over the ATF banning pistol braces, by defining them as short barreled rifles. There's no law that bans them, the ATF suddenlychanged their mind about it's interpretation after several decades. An EO that enshrines an equivalent of the Common Law Rule of Lenity for regulations, is totally within the president's power.

Comment: FWIW, the distinction he makes between the politically appointed part of the Executive branch, and the civil service, is common in the elementary school civics instruction of France and many other countries, even though the U.S. has not historically described itself in this manner. The U.S. has no distinction initially and the insulation of the civil service flowed initial from abuses of the patronage system by President Jackson, and then with independent agency formation and bureaucratization in the Great Depression and WWII.

Comment: Oh, so he means his own custom thing.  The "fourth (estate|power|branch)" is supposed to be the media.  Good luck to him with that, then.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed the President can’t/doesn’t micromanage them, but that doesn’t make them any less a part of the executive branch, because the President isn’t the entire executive branch. Or at least, so it seems to me, coming from Australia where the executive is specifically the Cabinet, not the Prime Minister.

Comment: @TimPederick True. And while he can't actually abolish these agencies, by appointing the right people and setting priorities he can effectively neuter them. E.g. Trump's Sec of Education had no background in education and scaled back lots of federal programs under her control.

Comment: What a moron. I'm going to ban the branch of government that does something, and just keep the politicians.